# how to resolve Error : for i in range(len(val)): TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() , it might be silly

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, selenium, selenium-webdriver

in my project i have to send a numpy board in Instagram dm , `sendMessage()` funtion works fine i can send str message but can not send that i have created by numpy , please help me

THANKS in advance

**My Code**

```
from time import sleep
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\saksh\\Desktop\\codeing\\Projects\\Connect 4\\chrome profiles\\chrome profile - 1")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options =  options , executable_path = r"C:\Users\saksh\Desktop\codeing\imported items\chromedriver v-90.exe")


ROW_COUNT = 6
COLUMN_COUNT = 7

def create_board():
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT, COLUMN_COUNT))

    return board


def send_board(board):
    board = str(np.flip(board, 0))
    board  = board.replace("0", "")
    board = board.replace("1", "")
    board =  board.replace("2", "⚫")
    

board = create_board()


def sendMessage(message , browser):
    message_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".ItkAi > textarea:nth-child(1)")
    message_box.send_keys(message)
    message_box.Keys.ENTER 

# manually go u any instagram dm 
# manually go u any instagram dm 
print("manually go u any instagram dm , and press enter") 

input("press enter !!")

sleep(5)

sendMessage(send_board(board) , browser)
```

ERROR

raceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\saksh\Desktop\codeing\Projects\Connect 4\temp1.py", line 46, in 
sendMessage(send_board(board) , browser)
File "c:\Users\saksh\Desktop\codeing\Projects\Connect 4\temp1.py", line 35, in sendMessage
message_box.send_keys(message)
File "C:\Users\saksh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
{'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
File "C:\Users\saksh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: `send_board()` does not `return` anything but you pass its result to `sendMessage()`. That means you are implicitly passing `None` to `sendMessage()`. Perhaps you intended to place `return board` inside `send_board()`?

Comment: yes thanks a lot , I can not up vote u because my  reputation is low

Comment: You can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error trace it's quite clear that in this block

```
def sendMessage(message , browser):
    message_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".ItkAi > textarea:nth-child(1)")
    message_box.send_keys(message)
    message_box.Keys.ENTER
```

This line

```
message_box.send_keys(message)
```

fails since the `message` is of `NoneType`.
That means that you passing there a `NoneType` object.
This is because you are calling this method by

```
sendMessage(send_board(board) , browser)
```

but the `send_board` method doesn't return a value / object.
So you actually send nothing, `NoneType` object to `sendMessage` method as a message to be inserted into the `message_box` element.